# In R, how do I create an error object? How do I throw an error on it later?

Tags: r, oop, exception, error-handling

In R, how do I create an error object?

Once I have an error object, how do I throw an exception on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `base` package contains function for creating error objects:

```
e <- base::simpleError("Something went wrong!")
```

An error object is just an S3 with class `error`:

```
inherits(e, "error")

[1] TRUE
```

So you could build one using `structure`:

```
d <- structure(
    list(message = "Something went wrong!"), 
    .Names = c("message"), 
    class = c("error"))
```

You can throw the error using `stop`:

```
stop(e)
```

Comment: Farming of reputations?

Comment: Google it, there's no quick answer.